# Hiding form once all fields are correct

Tags: javascript

I need to hide a form and display a confirmation page once all of the fields are filled out correctly

This is my form..

```
    <div id="form">

    <form name="info">
    <p>
    <label>First Name</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="first-name"/> <span id="fn-error"> </span>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Last Name</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="last-name"/> <span id="ln-error"> </span>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Email</label> <br />
    <input type="text" id="email"/> <span id="email-error"> </span>
    </p>

    <p>
     <label>Email Confirmation </label><br />
     <input type="text" id="email-confirm"/> <span id="emailConfirm-error"> </span>
     </p>


    <p>
    <label>Phone Number </label> <br />
    <input type="text" id="phone"/> <span id="phone-error"> </span>
    </p>

    <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" onclick="" />
    </form>

</div>

<div id="confirmation">
    <h1>Confirmation</h1>
    <p id="info">
    </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my validation page...

```
    window.addEventListener('load', init)

function init(e)
{

    var firstName = document.querySelector('#first-name');
    var lastName = document.querySelector('#last-name');
    var email = document.querySelector('#email');
    var emailConfirm = document.querySelector('#email-confirm');
    var phoneNumber = document.querySelector('#phone');
    var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    var label = document.querySelectorAll('label');
    var fields = document.querySelectorAll("#form input[type=text]");
    var form = document.querySelector('#form');


    submit.addEventListener('click', Edit);
    submit.addEventListener('click', EmailConfirm);
    submit.addEventListener('click', Results);

    function Edit(e)
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        {
            if (fields[i].value=="")
            {
                span[i].innerHTML = "*";
                span[i].style.color = "red"
                label[i].style.color = "red";
            }
            else
            {
                span[i].innerHTML="";
                label[i].style.color = "black";
            }
        }
    }

    function EmailConfirm(e)
    {
            if (email.value !== emailConfirm.value)
            {
                span[2].innerHTML = "Emails do not match";
                span[3].innerHTML = "Emails do not match"
            }
            else
            {
                span[2].innerHTML = "";
                span[3].innerHTML = "";
            }
    }

    function Results(e)
    {


    }
```

I need to be able to hide the form once all of the fields are filled in and the email and email confirmation match and display a confirmation page that will print out all of the information that is filled in, but i cant seem to figure out that once all information is correct to hide the form.

Comment: I think that will solve it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

**This could be a potential solution to your problem.**

Grab the form element and after your custom validation passes you can either

`const form = document.querySelector('#form');`

1. Use CSS to 'display: none' the form i.e. 
   `form.style.display = 'none';`
2. Use JS to remove the element from the DOM 
   `form.parentNode.removeChild(form);`

Those are the ways I usually do this sort of thing. let me know if it helps.

Comment: I need then form to be able to hide and display a confirmation page once all of the validation is true but that seems to just hide the form whether the validation is true or  not

Comment: Yes wrap the `form.style.display = 'none';` in an if statement to check if your validation passes. i.e.

```let validated = false;
if (email.value !== emailConfirm.value)
            {
                span[2].innerHTML = "Emails do not match";
                span[3].innerHTML = "Emails do not match"
            }
            else
            {
                span[2].innerHTML = "";
                span[3].innerHTML = "";
                validated = true;
            }
if (validated) {
   form.style.display = 'none';
}```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Check to see if any value has been entered

function validate() {
 const val1 = document.getElementById('one').value;
 const val2 = document.getElementById('two').value;

 if ((val1.length <= 0) || (val2.length <= 0)) {
   alert('Please fill out the form'); // If form is NOT filled out
   return false;   
 }
   alert('Congrats. All done, buddy :)');
   return true;  // Otherwise return TRUE and make them disappear
 }


// This is our function that uses CSS to target specific elements and
// hide them, depending on our 'basic' logic implemented here

function hideIt() {
       const x = document.getElementById('one');
       const y = document.getElementById('two');
       const z = document.getElementById('three');



if(validate()) { // If it ends up 'true' hide the HTML elements
        x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        y.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        z.style.visibility = 'hidden';

  } else {
        x.style.visibility = 'visible';
        y.style.visibility = 'visible';
        z.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="heading">Hide inputs:</h1>


<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="one" /> 
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="two"/>
  <!- Here we take advantage of our 'hideIt function -->
  <button onclick="hideIt()" type="button" id="three">Try Me</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Obviously, you can tweak this a lot more, but this is how I would do it, or at least it's a good starting point. Hope it helps :)